# AuthorizeAttribute with ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-roles

I have a controller which is protected by the `[Authorize]` attribute.

This works very good (I am sent back to login if I am not logged in), but I wish to add some roles to this attribute, I've read that its possible to do something like `[Authorize(Roles = "Customer"]` but when I do this I am instantly sent back to the login page on my application?

Is this `Roles` override not working with the new ASP.NET Identity? On my user creation I am adding the user to the by the following code:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser {UserName = model.Username};
var result = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Customer");
    SignIn(user, false);

    return RedirectToAction("Done");
}
```

And according to the database the user is in this role. Why is this not working? Am I missing a configuration or some sort?

Comment: Are you sure that user is in the Customer role?

Comment: Yes, the customer is coming from a constant I use

Comment: I mean, when you go to Project -> ASP.NET Configuration, go to security tab then click Create/Manage Roles.  Check for your Role.  Then go to users and check for your user. Be sure to check out part 7 of the Music Demo for Microsoft http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-7

Comment: That is for the old Membership - I am using ASP.NET Identity?

Comment: Sorry, you are correct.  Please see my answer (which I am about the write).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question.

The reason this was not working (hours of digging around) it was because my context had the following:

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

**This made lazyloading disabled** and therefore roles not included, when the user was loaded!

So the fix was to enable this or remove the line.

**UPDATE: 2015-05-01**

This was a bug, fixed in the 2.0.0-alpha1 release. Thus, this workaround is no longer necessary going forward, and the Roles will load regardless of this setting.

[Does Identity Owin require LazyLoading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868836/does-identity-owin-require-lazyloading)

Comment: wow! hit the same issue, spent all of last night trying to figure out why claims were not loading for user roles! Great catch, thanks!

Comment: Nice find. Also had me scratching my head for hours. I'm not sure why it needs to rely on lazy loading to get roles for a user. Would love to see some more in-depth insights into this. Anyone?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this behavior with the latest release of ASP.Net Identity. I had a different issue, which led me to this post, however, neither Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false, nor toggling Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled makes any difference. It loads Roles in both cases.

Comment: It turns out that this was a bug, which was subsequently fixed. Thus, we no longer need such a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868836/does-identity-owin-require-lazyloading

Comment: I will update the question/answer when im on a computer again. Thanks for this

Comment: @janhartmann many thanks for your post! It was a great part of my path of discovery.

Answer (score 0):

Create a role like so:

```
RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new MyDbContext()));
var roleresult = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
```

Then, add a user like so:

```
var currentUser = UserManager.FindByName(user.UserName); 
var roleresult = UserManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, "Superusers");
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is already the way I create roles and adding users to roles, the problem is that the the check for the role is false.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with AspNet Identity in my case. Are you sure you:

- haven't customized Authorization filters or done it right?
- haven't reconfigured authentication/authorization in web.config?
- have proper entries in AspNet Identity tables: AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, AspNetUserRoles (the role exists and the user has it)?

Comment: How should the authorization look like in web.config? I am using no other filters than errorhandling.

Comment: Are there any elements named authentication or authorization in your web.config, what are they values?

Comment: No there is not. I have even tried putting the default: <modules><remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" /></modules> in together with <authentication mode="None" /> - without any luck either.

Comment: Last check: table data entries (Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> DefaultConnection [might be other] -> there are AspNet Identity tables). If there is a correct match - no idea without looking at code.

Comment: Yes they are there. Also filled with correct data and correct relationship. I am beginning to think maybe when the user is loaded its roles is not populated. Lazy loading. But i havent configurered my app not to use LL

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this answer: [ASP.NET Identity check user roles is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20138596/2871663)

In your case, while checking for the case, compare the case of IdentityRole record and Authorize Attribute. Do not compare with the `UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Customer");`

Answer (score 0):

i write a sample to test it,it works good.so i think there 2 points
1.you cookie not save to browser
2.you cookie not with a role info

check you cookie, is there a cookie named ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie" (default name)
if not so check you broswer allow write cookie,or the code you write cookie
if exsit ,you can create a class extends

```
ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
```

and config

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            TicketDataFormat=new T()

        });
```

new T() is the class
in this class you need do

```
public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
```

and

```
public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText)
```

it is some thing about serialize
you can set a break point,and check the data,
in data.Identity.Claims (a IEnumerable< Claim>) should have a Claim with your role info