# How to configure UserName or Email ID for login in Asp.Net Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

i have created an admin user in my MVC app by seeding the database at startup. The Email is set to "Admin@test.com" and UserName is set to "Admin". This doesn't work as i realized that the application expects UserName on the Login page. And by default the Login page expects an Email ID in field. How do i configure the application to login using Email ID ? And even better how to configure it to accept both EMail ID and UserName ?

I tried below cases :

> 1. Email : Admin@Test.com UserName : Admin@Test.com

I am able to login using Admin@Test.com

> 2. EMail : Admin@Test.com, UserName : Admin

In this case login fails using Admin@Test.com, and the form does not accepts "Admin" as it's not a valid email format.

> 3. EMail : Admin@Test.com, UserName : AdminUserName@test.com

In this case login fails using Admin@Test.com, but succeeds using AdminUserName@Test.com

Below is the code of configuration in startup file :

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Adding the customized Application Context for Identity
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MySQLConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    services.AddMvc();

    // Set the default authentication policy to require users to be authenticated. 
    // requires: using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    //           using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
    services.AddMvc(config =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                         .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                         .Build();
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
}
```

The code for seeding the Admin role and user account :

```cs
public class AdminUserAndRoles
{
    public static async Task CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        //adding custom roles
        var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        string[] RoleNames = { "Administrator", "Guest" };
        IdentityResult roleResult;

        foreach (var roleName in RoleNames)
        {
            //creating the roles and seeding them to the database
            var roleExist = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
            if (!roleExist)
            {
                roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(roleName));
            }
        }

        //creating a super user who could maintain the web app
        var AdminUser = new ApplicationUser
        {                
            UserName = configuration.GetSection("AdminSettings")["UserName"],
            Email = configuration.GetSection("AdminSettings")["UserEmail"]
        };

        string UserPassword = configuration.GetSection("AdminSettings")["UserPassword"];
        var _user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(configuration.GetSection("AdminSettings")["UserEmail"]);

        if (_user == null)
        {
            var createPowerUser = await UserManager.CreateAsync(AdminUser, UserPassword);
            if (createPowerUser.Succeeded)
            {
                //here we tie the new user to the "Admin" role 
                await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(AdminUser, "Administrator");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code.

Comment: The configuration was default, but i've added the code for Identity Configuration and seeding the db with Role and Admin user.

Comment: You need to provide the login code.

Comment: @Brad I haven't written any code for Login. It's just the out-of-box login mechanism of Asp.Net Core. I used the MVC WebApp template to create the project in VS 2017.

Comment: Here I was thinking you had already made efforts to do that.  What you're trying to do is not configurable.  You have to program it yourself.   You should be able to find examples on the internet.

Comment: @Brad you mean to say, that this is the default behavior and cannot be configured without adding a code ? It would be good if you can share few relevant links.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, like it's a design flaw in the framework. I got help from this answer which is actually based on ASP.Net MVC 5. But the same issue is found in ASP.Net Core 2.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540656/7491048

The changes suggested in the link above are to be made in AccountController.cs

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot. The function PasswordSignInAsync, is expecting UserName as the first parameter, whereas by default EmailId is being passed to it.

Comment: It's not a design flaw.  If you allow the user to login using either email or username then you need to try and find the user by those fields.  If you find a user then you can try signing them in using the provided password.

Comment: @Brad The login page checks for Email Id and internally the framework is working on UserName. How can we justify this ?

Comment: It's code generated from a template.  It's not a framework.  You can modify the code any way you see fit to meet your requirements.  The generated project templates in VS are not to be treated as best practice or the way things are done.  They are only good to be used as a guide and then modified to suit your needs.